# How to create a multiIndex dataframe from a streaming csv file

Tags: python, pandas, multidimensional-array, pandas-groupby, multi-index

I'm streaming data to a csv file.
This is the request:

symbols=["SPY", "IVV", "SDS", "SH", "SPXL", "SPXS", "SPXU", "SSO", "UPRO", "VOO"]
each symbols has a list range from (0,8)

this is how it looks like in 3 columns:

```
-1583353249601,symbol,SH
-1583353249601,delayed,False
-1583353249601,asset-main-type,EQUITY
-1583353250614,symbol,SH
-1583353250614,last-price,24.7952
-1583353250614,bid-size,362
-1583353250614,symbol,VOO
-1583353250614,bid-price,284.79
-1583353250614,bid-size,3
-1583353250614,ask-size,1
-1583353250614,bid-id,N
```

my end goal Is to reshape the data:
[this is what I need to achieved.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CrSL.png)

the problems that I encounter where:

not being able to group by tiemstamp and not being able to pivot.

1)I tried to crate a dict and so later It can be passed to pandas, but I m missing data in the process. 
I need to find the way to group the data that has the same timestamp.it looks like that omit the lines with the same timestamp.

code:

```
new_data_dict = {}
with open("stream_data.csv", 'r') as data_file:
    data = csv.DictReader(data_file, delimiter=",")
    for row in data:
       item = new_data_dict.get(row["timestamp"], dict())
       item[row["symbol"]] = row["value"]
       new_data_dict[row['timestamp']] = item
data = new_data_dict
data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
data.T
print(data.T)
```

2)this is an other approach, I was able to group by timestamp by creating 2 different data, but I can not split the value column in to multiple columns to be merge late matching indexes.

code:

```
data = pd.read_csv("tasty_hola.csv",sep=',' ) 

data1 = data.groupby(['timestamp']).apply(lambda v: v['value'].unique())
data = data.groupby(['timestamp']).apply(lambda v: v['symbol'].unique())
data1 = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':data1.index, 'value':data1.values})
```

At this moment I don't know if the logic that I m trying to apply is the correct one. very lost not being able to see the light at the end of the tunnel.
Thank you very much

Comment: Your data is not in a tabluar format, but more like blocks. Looking at the first 6 rows, we get values of `last-price`, `bid-size` w.r.t `symbol = 'SH'` for timestamp `-1583353250614`. You need to converts this `blocks` into a table.